# Using Jmeter how to skip loading of IFrame

Tags: java, jmeter

I have recorded a scenario in Jmeter, I have webpage which is having `Iframe` in it. which loads another webpage from same domain.

`Retrieve All Embedded Resources` is checked but I don't want that `Iframe` should get loaded. I have tried adding *.css,*.js.*.png in `URLs must match` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @4m01 yes, its from same domain.

Comment: I should have read the question carefully :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can stop downloading all embedded resources in the `iframe`. In a way, `iframe` won't get loaded.

Please note that - requested page which has `iframe` embedded will still show the `iframe` in HTML response but subsequent calls that `iframe` will make to download embedded resources can be stopped.

Here the sample `iframe` [example](https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/iframe). Editor being displayed on the page is in `iframe`. So if you load the page all the resources get downloaded.

[image: Iframe example]

So lets try this in `jmeter` :

[image: iframe allowed 1]

[image: iframe alowed 2]

and results of this call as same in developer console-
[image: iframe allowed result].

Now, block the `iframe` using `URLs must match` functionality.

I peeked in the respons of eariler request and blocked the `iframe` using below regex pattern :

```
^(nested_frames)*?
```

Here is the image:
[image: iframe blocked]

And here is the response for this request:
[image: iframe blocked result]

I have uploaded the JMX file on [Github](https://github.com/4M01/SO/blob/master/Using%20Jmeter%20how%20to%20skip%20loading%20of%20IFrame.jmx) if you want to play around.

Comment: @Amogh did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems a little bit weird as well-behaved JMeter test should have the same network footprint as the real browser does (it applies to embedded resources, [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching), [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), etc.) so if the real browser does load the page from the domain you're testing the JMeter test needs to do the same.

If you still need to exclude the iframe from your JMeter test you can "blacklist" the "another webpage" from being loaded via "URLs must match" section of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like:

```
^((?!the-webpage-you-don-want-here).)*$
```

More information: [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)